# Make JSON object with variables C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to save a JSON file in C# with variables from user input. I am using Visual Studio with `Newtonsoft.Json`. Does anyone know how to create a JSON object with variables of **name**, **description**, and **code**.

Comment: Look up `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and the `FileWriter`. Link those two together and you'll be able to write a JSON string to a file.

Comment: The question is unclear. There are a *LOT* of JSON tutorials for .NET, as it's used in all web app frameworks. All of them use variables. What you call `variable` though is actually a field. All tutorials show how to serialize an object with some fields to JSON one way or another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the following class:

```cs
public class CustomClass {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Saving class objects as JSON file:

```cs
var user = new CustomClass() {
    Name = "John Wick",
    Job = "Businessman",
    Age = 42
};

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\user.json", jsonString);
```

Loading JSON files and converting them to C# objects:

```
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\user.json");
CustomClass? user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomClass>(jsonString);
```

---

Additional:
By default, parsing will map the property names directly. Parsing the example from above to JSON would return:

```json
{
  "Name": "John Wick",
  "Job": "Businessman",
  "Age": 42
}
```

If you need to parse JSON objects, where the stored properties are different from the property names of your class, you can "rename" them by using property tags.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class CustomClass {
    [JsonProperty("user_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("user_job")]
    public string Job { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("user_age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

When parsed, this will return the following output:

```json
{
  "user_name": "John Wick",
  "user_job": "Businessman",
  "user_age": 42
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A sample for you:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new {
      name ="Your Name",
      description="This is my name",
      code="007"
    };
    
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\myJson.json", json);
}
```

Comment: An alternative is to use `JToken.FromObject` then call `ToString` on the result